# Safari returning permission denied for notifications using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    getToken(messaging, {vapidKey: "BDdPw4DcKQqPO----------------"}).then((currentToken) => {
      if (currentToken) {
        this.sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    });
  }
});`
```

I want to get the token when permission is granted and safari always is returning permission denied. Can someone please help ?

Comment: `denied` means *The user has explicitly denied permission for the current origin to display system notifications.* - you can of course undo that choice in your browser

Comment: Notifications are enabled. @JaromandaX

Comment: your experience says otherwise